# How does HQL's current_timestamp() work?

Tags: hql

Does the hql function current_timestamp() use the time from the server the java code is running on or the server the database is running on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HQL queries are translated to SQL queries, and SQL queries are executed by the database. So the `current_timestamp()` equivalent SQL function will be executed on your database server.

Comment: I don't think this is completely true though - I have a production Postgresql database server on AWS that is on central time (CST), however, using HQL query with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP yields an output of a UTC Timestamp. If it was dependent on the server, this shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

In hibernate, for every database, there're `Dialect` classes. Those are adapters for that specific databases. The functions like `current_timestamp` are defined in those classes. For instance, MySQL 5.7 Dialect is:

```java
public class MySQL57Dialect extends MySQL55Dialect {
    public MySQL57Dialect() {
        super();

        registerColumnType( Types.TIMESTAMP, "datetime(6)" );
        registerColumnType( Types.JAVA_OBJECT, "json" );
        final SQLFunction currentTimestampFunction = new StaticPrecisionFspTimestampFunction("now", 6 );

        registerFunction( "now", currentTimestampFunction );
        registerFunction( "current_timestamp", currentTimestampFunction );
        registerFunction( "localtime", currentTimestampFunction );
        registerFunction( "localtimestamp", currentTimestampFunction );
        registerFunction( "sysdate", new StaticPrecisionFspTimestampFunction( "sysdate", 6 ) );

    }

    public boolean supportsRowValueConstructorSyntaxInInList() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

As you can see there're function registrations there.
[Full Code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/e5dc635a52362f69b69acb8d5b166b69b165dbbd/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL57Dialect.java) is in hibernate in the GitHub page.