# Hibernate "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" HQL query returns UTC timestamp, even though DB is in CST

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, timestamp, hql

I have a API that uses a Spring data JPA/Hibernate framework using HQL to call my database, which is a Postgresql DB instance on AWS. The problem is that my database is in CST, and we load in data with CST timestamps with coupons for customers, and we perform some logic/comparisons with this with the intention of it all being in CST; however, the HQL queries using the "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" function appear to be returning UTC timestamps, resulting in all the relationship operator statements (i.e. `customerCoupons.expiredDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) that compare the coupon expiration with current timestamp to be **wrong**.

The query looks something like this:

```
@Query( value = SELECT customerCoupons FROM CustomerCouponsEntity AS customerCoupons " 
WHERE customerCoupons.couponCode = :couponCode "
AND customerCoupons.expiredDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP "
AND customerCoupons.startDate <= CURRENT TIME"

List<CustomerCouponsEntity> findByCouponCode(@Param("couponCode") String couponCode);
```

So you can see I can search by a "coupon code" and find all coupons for customers that are **not** expired. *The problem is* my database is in central time (CST), however, when I deploy this Spring Boot app to AWS cloud test my API, these HQL queries are 100% returning a UTC Timestamp. Even worse, when I and other friends of mine working on this app test locally, the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP seems to return whatever timezone the user is in (i.e. if my friends runs this in EST timezone at 6pm and we set an expiration for 5pm CST, it will have already been expired for him since the HQL query will return a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP == 6pm EST and not CST, like it should be, since the Database is in CST. This same behavior happens for users in CST or PST when running locally).

I have proved this, because I have injected "coupons" into my database with central time (CST) expiration dates and as you can see above, this HQL query, only returns non-expired coupons from my database. However, when I inject say a coupon to expire at a timestamp of 2021-02-25 22:00:00, which is 10PM and it is 9PM central currently, I get **no data** returned from my API. However, at 9PM CST, if I change this 10PM == 22:00:00 timestamp to UTC time, which is equal to 04:00:00 UTC, my API **returns data** and as soon as it hits 04:0:00 UTC, or 10PM CST, then it returns 0 records. **So I know**, despite my database being configured as CST in AWS, this HQL function for some reason, is returning UTC time.

Can anyone explain to me why this is? I found another stack overflow post where the user stated the "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" function should run on the SQL Server database, even though is HQL, but from what I see, this is not happening.
[How does HQL's current_timestamp() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254130/how-does-hqls-current-timestamp-work)

Furthermore, tested this Spring boot app locally with other developers in different timezones, we saw that the HQL query with "CURRRENT_TIMESTAMP" looks like it actually depends on the users local time zone; i.e. records that were set to expire at EST times, like 4pm, where **still queryable**  via my API (which uses this HQL query to query the database), even though I was on a zoom call with another developer in the EST timezone and he was getting 0 records. So I'm 99.9% sure this HQL "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" is dependent on the systems local time zone for some reason. Though, I know the database is set in AWS to CST, but I believe system logging is at UTC and I'm not sure about any other settings....

I was planning to fix the issue with something like this:

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP at TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago'
```

It looks to work perfectly fine locally; is this the best solution and can anyone explain the behavior I have seen with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in the HQL hibernate sql queries?

Comment: This seems to be the same problem you already asked about here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66353107/spring-boot-api-calling-postgres-db-with-timestamp-column-datatype-weird-behavio Please delete one of the questions or make it clearer why both questions have merit.

Comment: I deleted the other question. Do you know why the Hibernate SQL query seems to be dependent on local system timezone when many posts on google/SO state that it should be independent and run on db server, like any other SQL statement?

Comment: Sorry, can't help with that one.

Comment: The best solution is to just use UTC on the database and application server. Only translate time zones when the information passes to users e.g. the browser, and even then, it might be better to do the translation on the client instead if possible.